# Exponential of two different derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I know that

$$\begin{align*}
\exp\left(\alpha\frac{d}{dx}\right)f(x)=f(x+\alpha)\,,
\end{align*} \tag{1}$$

but I am looking for a definition for

$$\begin{align*}
\exp\left(\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)f(x,y)\,,
\end{align*} \tag{2}$$

so, the first question is: **Is there a definition for the previous expression?.**

Now, in the particular case where $f(x,y)$ is a product of two Gaussian functions centered in $y_{0}$ and $x_{0}$, that is $f(x,y)=\exp\left[-k_{2}(y-y_{0})^{2}\right]\exp\left[-k_{1}(x-x_{0})^{2}\right]$ (with $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ being real or complex constants), so, the second question is: **Is it valid to apply equation (1) in order to displace first a Gaussian function**?, I mean

$$\begin{align*}
\exp\left(\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\exp\left[-k_{2}(y-y_{0})^{2}\right]\exp\left[-k_{1}(x-x_{0})^{2}\right]\,,
\end{align*} \tag{3}$$

taking $\hat{c} = \alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, the above expresión is 
$$\begin{align*}
\exp\left(\hat{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\exp\left[-k_{2}(y-y_{0})^{2}\right]\exp\left[-k_{1}(x-x_{0})^{2}\right]
\,,
\end{align*} \tag{4}$$
Using equation (1) the $y$ variable is displaced
$$\begin{align*}
\exp\left[-k_{2}(\left[y+\hat{c}\right]-y_{0})^{2}\right]\exp\left[-k_{1}(x-x_{0})^{2}\right]
\,,
\end{align*} \tag{5}$$
or
$$\begin{align*}
=\exp\left[-k_{2}\left(\left[y+\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]-y_{0}\right)^{2}\right]\exp\left[-k_{1}(x-x_{0})^{2}\right]
\
\end{align*} \tag{6}$$
then, the first exponential of above equation will become an operator that will act on the second exponential. I think that this procedure is wrong because if the exponentials of equation (3) are swapping, I would get

$$\begin{align*}
\exp\left[-k_{1}(x-x_{0})^{2}\right]
\exp\left[-k_{2}\left(\left[y+\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]-y_{0}\right)^{2}\right]\
\end{align*} \tag{7}$$

which clearly is not the same as the equation (6).

Comment: Basically what you want to do is to find the fundamental solution of the associated second order PDE which is an evolution equation defined by that operator $\partial_{xy}$. Then your operator is just given by convolution with that fundamental solution.

Comment: You can solve the equation in Fourier space though I doubt the fundamental solutions will be function-valued, and I also doubt there is an explicit expression for inverting that Fourier transform. then again it could be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions like $\exp(\alpha T),$ where $T$ is some operator and $\alpha$ is a constant, are defined by the Maclaurin expansion:
$$
\exp(\alpha T) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \alpha^n T^n
$$

Therefore,
$$
\exp\left(\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) f(x,y)
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \alpha^n \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)^n f(x,y)
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \alpha^n \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)^n \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)^n f(x,y),
$$
where the last equality is valid since partial derivatives commute if $f$ is smooth.